# Add custom key in fetched JSON

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am making simple blog website in React and when I fetch posts I am getting user id, who posted it. with this id I am making another `axios` where I get user with given id and then I assign `author` key to my fetched posts JSON like this:

```
export const getPosts = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    );
    for (const item of data) {
      let user = await getUser(item["userId"]);
      item["author"] = user.username;
    }
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error(err.message);
  }
};

export const getUser = async (id) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

This method causes 5-10 seconds delay to display posts. I am searching for faster and simpler way to display username to every post.
U also can tell me if there is better way to fetch data and display it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have done it the exact right way if there is no other endpoint available to fetch multiple post author information at a time.

Well, this is meant to be an answer, but I'd start with a question.

Do you have access to the maintainer or developer handling the Restful API endpoint you are trying to get from?

If yes?

Tell them to simply include the author information on the response for fetching the post(s)

Or simply provide you with an endpoint that allows you to get author information for many posts at a time.

If No

Go over the documentation provided (if any) and see if there is any endpoint that allows you to fetch author information for multiple posts with a single request.

If none of the above option seems to be a way, kindly remember to block the UI When fetching the resources.

You can also fetch for few authors first and display while fetching for more in the background or on request for more by user, that way you would give a better user experience.

Happy hacking and coding